# JQuery append() adding quotes and newlines and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an append statement that adds a single character at a time to a span. (The characters are pulled from a string by treating it like an array: `text[i]` and such.) I feel like it should be giving me this:

```
<span id="outputid0">text</span>
```

But instead it's giving me this:

```
<span id="outputid0">
  "t"
  "e"
  "x"
  "t"
</span>
```

I guess it makes sense, and this is not a real problem at the moment, but it is a bit awkward-looking and I'm not sure why it's happening. Can anyone explain this one for me?

Edit: Here's a link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Colin_Fredericks/XU745/), showing an example of what I was talking about. Thank you to ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, who seems to have diagnosed and solved the problem just fine without that. If anyone else would like to see it, there it is.

Comment: you have to show you code

Comment: Added code as per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append adds a child node after the last child node so each character is going to be a `text node` and that is why they are separated like that

If you want to add a character at a time you're better off taking whats there and concatenating the char to the string that's already there

You can do it like this using jQuery's [.text(function(){})](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) function

```
// where i = index and v = current text value
$('#outputid0').text(function(i,v){
     return v + "your new char";
});
```

[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xebcm/)

Comment: Definitely fixes my issue. Useful note to folks doing this: if you're using non-breaking spaces or other HTML entities, you'll want to use String.fromCharCode() to set them rather than using '&nbsp'. The text function will add '&nbsp;' literally rather than adding a non-breaking space, whereas append() adds the space.

Answer (score 0):

If I was a betting man, I'd say you are looping thru an array to generate what you want. Do something like this: Remember, I am only assuming how the data is setup - and only showing for example purposes.

```
var arr = ['t','e','x','t'];

// just '.join' the array


<span id="outputid0"></span>

// following in script tag
jQuery('#outputid0').text(arr.join(''));
```

Just to reiterate what Ehsan mentions above. You really need to include your code so there is no 'assuming' or 'guessing' at what you want to accomplish :-)